# When an image shows up in "page not found" in Watchdog, how to find the content containing the image link?

Tags: uri, log-messages

I disabled the countryicons_shiny module on my site, and now I'm getting some errors in Watchdog showing that the images weren't found:

```
Details
Type    page not found
Date    April 3, 2016
User    Anonymous
Location    https://www.example.com/sites/all/modules/contrib/countryicons_shiny/images/tw.png
Referrer    
Message sites/all/modules/contrib/countryicons_shiny/images/tw.png
Severity    warning
Hostname    1.1.1.1
Operations
```

I'm pretty sure this is a misconfigured view, but I have a ton of views and content types on my site, so I was hoping to find a way to identify the content (view, page, etc.) that is trying to display the icon.

I have all my views in features and I tried using `grep countryicons *` but no results are returned.

**How can I find what content is linking to the image when I only have the watchdog log "page not found entry?**

Comment: Did you search `countryicons` in theme and custom module files too?

Comment: Why not just run a link checker on your site and look for the pages containing 404s that way? If you're on a Mac, Integrity is great, it even has an option to search for missing images. It's also worth considering the requests may be being made by a search engine/other bot/someone who has a cached version of some pages

Comment: @Clive Basically all the pages on this site are only accessible to authenticated users.  I downloaded Integrity, but it doesn't look like it can log in to spider the site.

Comment: @skorzh No, I didn't-- good idea.  Unfortunately, I just checked there and didn't come up with anything, either.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the ultimate solution, but in this specific case, since I moved the icons into another module, to fix this particular error I just symlinked the folders:

```
mkdir countryicons_shiny
cd countryicons_shiny
ln -s ../mycustommodule/countryiconsdirectory images
```